# Apache/Tomcat returning Error 503

Tags: tomcat, apache2

Setup includes: Windows 7 Apache 2.2 Tomcat 5.5 mod_jk-1.2.30-httpd-2.2.3

After performing the appropriate installs, I can get to the Apache default page, and I can access the Tomcat on localhost as well. But when I try to access jsp-examples via Apache, I'm getting the following error 503:

> "Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to
>   service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.
>   Please try again later.

I checked apache and tomcat logs, but they do not report any exceptions there, would appreciate if anyone can point how can I find what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If Apache is coming back with a 503 error it means that it can't establish a connection to the backend server. In your case, via mod_jk and the tomcat connector. Both Tomcat and Apache need to be configured properly to communicate. Ensure that your tomcat listeners are set up properly (AJP in most cases) and that your worker configuration refers to that same AJP listener. Finally make sure to properly refer to the right worker in your httpd.conf, .htaccess or vhost file.

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTPD sometimes requires a kick to get it to recognise that a Tomcat service is available again. I don't know how this is done under Windows, but under Linux I do:

> service httpd reload

Sometimes that fails. Then I do:

> service httpd restart.

And then it works.

I need to find a permanent solution for this though. Every time Tomcat is restarted, I need to kick Apache again to get it to allow AJP connections again.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue got resolved by changing the order of PassProxy entry in ***10_proxy.conf*** file in `/etc/httpd/` for the URL entry I was hitting.

*Note : There could be many other issues for **503** error but surely related to `.conf` files.*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue:

> "Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Finally I find my server is under CC attacks, which occupy resources, so I apply a CC defense rule, then I solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this file with your fivorite editor
`/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf` make sure this file is not empty, it should have modules lines like `LoadModule ....`

add this code after LoadModule lines

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyTimeout 300
```

then reload the server `systemctl restart httpd`

this manipulation works for centos 7, tomcat 7, and apache webserver